# LinkButton unresponsive in Binded ListView

Tags: listview, webforms

Dynamically generated button can't be clicked in Google chrome sometimes

I have a listview web control and its datasource is binded at the page load event handler. 
The following code below shows a listview which its button is dynamically generated based on how many datarows in the datasource.

The problem is, sometimes, when the button is click, both client side alert and server side click event will not be fire. The chances of happening is 10-15%.

If it's not firing, I have to shift my mouse to the side to click and it will work normally. This only happens with Google Chrome. I have disabled all extensions in chrome but to no avail.

Please help!

```
<asp:ListView ID="productsList" ItemPlaceholderID="itemContainer" EnableViewState="false" OnItemDataBound="productsList_ItemDataBound" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">


<LayoutTemplate>
<ul class="nav-fade">
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemContainer" runat="server" />
</ul>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>

<li id="<%#(Eval("ID"))%>">

<asp:LinkButton href="" EnableViewState="false" ID="btnAddToCart" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="buttonclass" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" ></asp:LinkButton>

</li>

</ItemTemplate>
<EmptyDataTemplate>

</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: If you are binding the ListView on every page load, you are essentially losing the reference to the event handler when it's rebound, which is why it won't fire. Do you have more code to share? Right now your LinkButton doesn't have an attached event handler.

Comment: I'm binding the listview using DatasourceID. Therefore, the button in the itemtemplate will be generated in runtime. My button has a attached event handler, just that i didnt state over here